# Using jQuery to create a download button

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, download

I have currently made a download button using PHP but when you put your mouse over the link you are able to see the path of the file to download and this is not secure as you are able to change the path and download somebody elses file.

I would like to have this path hidden and I believe the best way by doing this button is using jQuery (correct me if im wrong).

This is what I have done:

```
<?php 
        $nombredir = str_pad($this->item->id, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        $path = 'media'.DS.'com_cspartners'.DS.'documentation';
        $path = str_replace('/administrator','',$path);
        $nombrePDF = "/".$nombredir.'_'.JText::_('COM_CSPARTNERS_NOMBRE_DOCUMENTATION_CONTRACT');
        $facturaFile=$path.DS.$nombredir;
        $pdfAdjunto = $facturaFile.$nombrePDF; //This is path and file name which appears in the link.
?>
```

This is my download button/link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $pdfAdjunto; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" id="jform_download_documentation" name="jform[download_documentation]"><?php echo JText::_("COM_CSPARTNERS_DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTATION_BUTTON"); ?></a>
```

Comment: URL are never secure. jQuery will not secure this (and JS will never secure something). To secure your download URL you can hide the real filename by using a random ID, a hash or something human can't guess.

Comment: @KevinLabécot how can that be done?

Comment: I think the problem here is not the button, its the document. If your document is doc1.pdf its pretty clear there must be a document doc2.pdf. So everybod is able to download it. To make it secure, add a random string to your document like doc1_gz758gujf6.pdf and use another string for user2..

Comment: @NicoMartin Thats a good idea too but I should still have the path hidden some way

Comment: Why? If you have http://yourname.com/docs/ where you have all your docs, that should be alright.. If a user has the link to doc1 hes not able to download doc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : bind click event to anchor tag and change `href` link to `href="#"`

Anchor -

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" 
   id="jform_download_documentation" 
   name="jform[download_documentation]">
  <?php echo JText::_("COM_CSPARTNERS_DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTATION_BUTTON"); ?>
</a>
```

and create one hidden input with value equal to link

```
<input type="hidden" 
       id="jform_download_documentation_hidden" 
       value="<?php echo $pdfAdjunto; ?>">
```

jQuery: on click event of button submit the url

```
$(function(){
  $('#jform_download_documentation').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = $('#jform_download_documentation_hidden').val();
  });
});
```

Comment: For some reason its adding this to my URL when it didnt do so before: `/index.php/en/certification-partner-application/`. This is the complete URL which appears: `/demo-certifications/index.php/en/certification-partner-application/media/com_cspartners/documentation/0000000001/0000000001_Partner%20Contract.pdf`

Comment: This is the link where my button is placed: `/demo-certifications/index.php/en/certification-partner-application` and it seems to be adding the link of the file after `index.php/en/` which makes the link incorrect.

Comment: do view source of your page and check the value of hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use another php script for example

```
<?php

 // generate file path using database or find file using PHP
 $path = '/some/path/';

 // get file name from dabatase, or set it as a const or param
 $filename= $_GET['filename']; // parase it for security

 // combine path and filename
$filename = $path.$filename;

 header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
 readfile($filename);
?>
```

save it as 'download.php', and then when u create your download button, pass only one param.
The download link should look something like that : download.php?id=2323 (id : 2323 in database -> 'some_document.doc' )

or

download/some-2323-file  - then parase param, get ID and voila :) no one see file path :)